# SendGrid not found in HTTPTrigger function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an **Azure Function** that will be trigerred by HTTP using VSCode in a macOS.

Using official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local), I successfully create an HTTP Trigered azure function in my local machine.

Now I want to send a email during this function, but when I add a **senGrid** reference, I got a compilation error :

> The following 1 functions are in error:
>   [15/01/2018 21:51:12] ResetPasswordSendEmail: C# compilation service error: Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   [15/01/2018 21:51:12] . Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

**The azure function :**

```
#r "SendGrid"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, out Mail message)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    string email = data.email;
    string password = data.password;

    message = new Mail
    {        
        Subject = "Azure news"          
    };

    bool isOk = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password);

    return isOk ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "EmailError");
}
```

**The function json :**

```
{
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [{
            "authLevel": "function",
            "name": "req",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in"
        },
        {
            "name": "message",
            "type": "sendGrid",
            "direction": "out",
            "apiKey": "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey"
        },
        {
            "name": "$return",
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to keep the code at the same place and not have the **azure functions** outside code management (GIT).

If somebody knows how to solve my issue, please help :D

Comment: I think you need to reference NuGet package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid`

Comment: Where ? I do not see any csproj and adding manually a **project.json** do not resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are developing locally on a Mac, you are probably using v2 "core" version of `func` CLI tool.

Navigate to your project root folder (where `host.json` is) and execute the following command:

```
func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid -v 3.0.0-beta4
```

This will add `SendGrid` binaries to `bin` folder of your Function App.

Then, your script seems to be a mix of v1 and v2 functions. For example, `CreateResponse()` doesn't belong to `HttpRequest` and `Mail` class is not in `SendGrid` assembly. Here is a very simplistic example of sending a mail from HTTP function:

```cs
public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, out SendGridMessage message)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.AddTo("you@gmail.com");
    message.AddContent("text/html", "Test body");
    message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("test@test.com"));
    message.SetSubject("Subject");

    return new OkObjectResult("OK");
}
```

Comment: It's my first azure function. So for sure I missed lot informations, Thanks for the extensions install. I 'am trying to install the extensions and rebuild the function

Comment: @OrcusZ Did you get `SendGrid.dll` in you `bin` folder and `function-extensions` folder?

Comment: I Install it in my Function project instead of my function folders and it works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and description, you might get a mix of creating sendgrid on portal and on VScode.

Here I create HttpTrigger function and add sendgrid on portal, you could refer to the code as below:

**The azure function:**

```
#r "SendGrid"
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Net;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, out Mail message)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    message = new Mail
    {        
        Subject = "Azure news"          
    };

    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddTo(new Email("example@test.com"));   

    Content content = new Content
    {
        Type = "text/plain",
        Value = "msp"
    };
    message.AddContent(content);
    message.AddPersonalization(personalization);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"hello");
}
```

**The function json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "apiKey": "sendgridkey",
      "from": "example2@test.com",
      "subject": "hello",
      "text": "hello sendgrid",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

For more detail, you can read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-sendgrid) to learn how to use sendgrid in Azure Functions.